# Disabling certain WebStorm inspections only in specific file types or contexts

Tags: webstorm

I'm working on an Aurelia project and as the part of the templating system use references to my view-model JavaScript files inside of my view HTML files. For example:

```html
<label>${contact.lastName}</label>

<input value.bind="contact.lastName">
```

In both lines, WebStorm correctly identifies `contact.lastName` as a JavaScript fragment and therefore highlights it with the "Expression statement is not assignment or call" inspection. While this is technically true, it's not a problem in this context.

I know that the simple solution is to disable that inspection in WebStorm, but that would also presumably disable it in all of my actual JavaScript files too where I would still want this inspection to happen.

What I want to know is, is there a way to turn off this inspection *only in HTML files*?

Comment: Do you have aurelia plugin installed? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8567-aureliastorm

Comment: Yep, I think that's what's allowing Webstorm to recognize those fragments as JavaScript in the first place.

Comment: Contexts -- no; File types (any files, even random collection of them (but whole file)) -- yes. Just create custom Scope where you would list all such files/folders and then configure that particular inspection: add new rule for newly created scope and turn inspection off for it.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, making a custom scope that just doesn't include HTML files was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to turn off this inspection only in HTML files?

Yes -- every inspection can be altered on scope level (scope works with whole files). By default every inspection has 1 rule that affects whole project.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Scopes`

   Go there and create a [custom Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.2/scopes.html) that would include such unwanted files/folders.
2. Save changes (either `Apply` ... or use `OK` and re-open Settings screen again)
3. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
4. Locate inspection which you wish to alter.
5. Create new rule for recently created Scope. For that just click on `In All Scopes` button (it's a button when only 1 rule is defined) and choose that scope.

   [image]
6. Now just disable this inspection for that scope.

   [image]

*(Screenshots are for another language/inspection and done in older IDE version but everything else remains the same)*

Official help pages:

- [Configuring Inspection for Different Scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.2/changing-the-order-of-scopes.html)
- [Disabling and Enabling Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.2/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html)